# how to move user input array value to end of array and set it to 0?

Tags: c++

What I need, is make program where user type 10 integers in array and then type one more integer which need to replace with 0 and move to the end of final array.

Tried out everything what I can find in google, but didn't work still.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int i, array[10], v;

cout << "Please enter 10 integer elements of an array!\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "array[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
cout << "Now, enter the integer, 'V': ";
    cin >> v;
    cout << endl;
cout << "The final array is:\n" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "array[" << i << "]: " << array[i] << endl;
        if (array[i] == v)
        {
            v = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    cout << "array[" << array[8] << "]: " << v << endl;
```

This is how far I am done, almost finished, but don't know how to make it proper, to see in final only 10 array values, not 11, when user enter the same value of main array.

[there is final result, how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PV3f.png)
Because I guess you will not understand anything what I need from this description, because my English is trash ;/

Comment: `i` is shadowed by the declaration in the for loop, and not accessible outside it's scope.

Comment: What happens if the array contains more than one occurrence of v??

Comment: Why do you set `v` to `0` if `array[i] == v`? You want to set an index of the array to `0` yes?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)` is a very convoluted way of doing something exactly once. The significance of the ninth element is also very unclear.

Comment: guys i have 0 understanding about all this sht... i dont know even what i am doing, so i cant explain you why i doing that or that...its black image for me, i just need finish this homework and i dont want to think about this trash more.. Our teacher start learn c++ for total beginners, he said because then we will have easier to start coding with another languages.. I think its biggest mistake to start learn programming with c++...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is code for moving all equal elements in array, you can refer it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int array[N];
    int v;

    cout << "Please enter 10 integer elements of an array!\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "array[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Now, enter the integer, 'V': ";
    cin >> v;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The final array is:\n" << endl;

    int pos = 0;
    // move element which are not equal backward
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] != v)
        {
            array[pos] = array[i];
            ++pos;
        }
    }
    // set value in remaining position to 0
    for ( ; pos < N; ++pos){
        array[pos] = 0;    
    }

    // print output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cout << "array[" << i << "]: " << array[i] << endl;    
    }


}
```

Comment: Yep, that is what i was looking for! Thanks you so match! :) But can you explain what is k? Because i cant see that you declare it somewhere? Also i will make your code for solution, thanks man!

Comment: hi, i declared k in for loop (int k = i; k < 9; ++k). it is for moving value of array after we meet 'V' backward, and at the end, set the last element of array to 0. does this make sense?

Comment: ou ok, it means you dont need to declare k on top of code? where is  int i, array[10], v; ? Thanks for explain :) Ok i got it, you can declare even in for loop :) Or if you defined on top then you can write like this ? ->> (k = i; k < 9; ++k) without int i am right?

Comment: actually, you don't need to declare i at top of code. of course we have to declare array[10], v as they are not declared any where else. in this case, we will have 2 variables naming 'i' and it will priority 'i' in inner first ( i at top of code consider as outer variable) ... i think you are newbie of c++, please take time to learn about it :)

Comment: yes, you are right, just "without int k", not "without int i"

Comment: Ye, i am very new to c++, and don't want to even go deeper, just need this for school...I think its the worst thing to start learn c++ for beginners in programming, i learning html, css, by myself that's all for now :) This is nightmare.. :D Thanks for help, appreciate!

Comment: Does not work when array is {1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1}; When v = 1. Output is   `array[0]: 1
array[1]: 2
array[2]: 1
array[3]: 1
array[4]: 1
array[5]: 0
array[6]: 0
array[7]: 0
array[8]: 0
array[9]: 0`

Comment: Thank you so much for your info. Yes, i have found the problem, issue in case of 2 elements are equal which they are next to each other, i will update code on tomorrow. It is midnight in my country now.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the i:th value in the array with zero, you write `array[i] = 0`, not `v = 0`.
To copy the i:th element to the last position, you write `array[9] = array[i]`.

Also, you should modify the array first and then print it, not print it as you go.

Comment: More closer with this, but still not what it should be. <br> I have now 0 in the end of final array, but that value of V integer still show in final array, it should be gone and see 0 in the end of array. Like they moving from bottom to top. Can you please see that picture from first post?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    const size_t MAX_SIZE = 10;
    size_t i = 0, array[MAX_SIZE], v;

    cout << "Please enter 10 integer elements of an array!\n" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        cout << "array[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Now, enter the integer, 'V': ";
    cin >> v;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The final array is:\n" << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        if (i == MAX_SIZE) {
            break;
        }

        if (array[i] == v) {

            for (size_t j = i; j < MAX_SIZE - 1; j++) {
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
            }

            array[MAX_SIZE - 1] = 0;
            continue;
        }

        cout << "array[" << i << "]: " << array[i] << endl;

        i++;
    }

}
```

_

You can also do it with a for loop.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; /*EMPTY*/) {

    if (array[i] == v)
    {
        for (size_t j = i; j < MAX_SIZE - 1; j++) {
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
        }

        array[MAX_SIZE - 1] = 0;
        continue;
    }

    cout << "array[" << i << "]: " << array[i] << endl;

    i++;
}
```

_

```
Please enter 10 integer elements of an array!

array[0]: 1
array[1]: 1
array[2]: 1
array[3]: 2
array[4]: 1
array[5]: 1
array[6]: 1
array[7]: 1
array[8]: 1
array[9]: 1

Now, enter the integer, 'V': 1

The final array is:

array[0]: 2
array[1]: 0
array[2]: 0
array[3]: 0
array[4]: 0
array[5]: 0
array[6]: 0
array[7]: 0
array[8]: 0
array[9]: 0
```

_

```
Please enter 10 integer elements of an array!

array[0]: 1
array[1]: 1
array[2]: 1
array[3]: 2
array[4]: 1
array[5]: 1
array[6]: 1
array[7]: 1
array[8]: 1
array[9]: 1

Now, enter the integer, 'V': 2

The final array is:

array[0]: 1
array[1]: 1
array[2]: 1
array[3]: 1
array[4]: 1
array[5]: 1
array[6]: 1
array[7]: 1
array[8]: 1
array[9]: 0
```